# React/ES6 import node module library

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have an installed node module which has some libraries it makes use of so for example I can see in the following

```
node_modules
|_@module
  |_submodule
    |_ lib
      |_ somelibrary.js
```

I'd like to be able to make use of that so I try to use some function like so

```
import * as library from '@module/submodule/lib/somelibrary';

library.someSuperCoolUtil();
```

However I get an error "reference error library is not defined". Am I doing this right?

Comment: `lib` is meant to be private :)

Comment: @Hitmands is right. usually the module file you should access is index.js no further than that